# How to write data to common core data from extension?

Tags: ios, core-data, today-extension

I want to write data from an extension. I have set up common core data using app groups and fetch requests are working. When I try to **save the data from extension**, I get NSPersistentStoreSaveError with no data in user info dictionary.

When I initialize the PersistentContainer, I get the following log:
attempt to add read-only file at path  private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/D7000EE9-DE84-4EAC-B481-7D8E2B029712/. This will be a hard error in the future; you must specify the NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?